# Have behavior depend on type parameter

Tags: rust

Can you statically pattern match or dispatch based on type parameter? I know you could call a trait method on it, but if you're already inside a struct implementation and need to work on the fields in your struct, calling another trait seems convoluted.

Here's a simplified example:

```
trait Childs {}
struct Child1 {}
impl Childs for Child1 {}
struct Child2 {}
impl Childs for Child2 {}

struct Other {
  c1s: Vec<Child1>,
  c2s: Vec<Child2>,
}
impl Other {
  fn something<C:Childs>(&self, o:C) {
    // TODO: Depending on type of C, push it to c1s or c2s
    // Maybe could do a Switch trait and something like:
    // (C::switch(self.c1s, self.c2s).push(o)
    // But seems odd.
  }
}
```

My understanding is that rust compiles a new method for each type that is used for that method anyway, so it seems like there ought to be a way to specify different code for those cases.

Update:
@cafce25 gave a well written answer for the above. It was much like what I had already done (I should have mentioned it originally):

```
pub trait Childs: Switch {}
pub trait Switch {
    fn switch<T>(a:T, b:T) -> T;
}
impl Switch for Child1 {
    fn switch<T>(a:T, _:T) -> T {
        return a;
    }
}
impl Switch for Child2 {
    fn switch<T>(_:T, b:T) -> T {
        return b;
    }
}
```

This seems to be a lot of boilerplate for the equivalent of a one line conditional. Next time maybe I need to switch between three, or need to do some other operation (+ vs. -, filter vs. not, etc.). That could cause an explosion of code.

And what if Childs/Child1/2 were defined in a different crate? The above might still work, but the orphan rule might limit some possibilities.

Is there some other approach for this type of static dispatch?

Comment: If `Childs` trait modifiable then you can apply this kind of [solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4e0794098e1ef2dc111bf338784d429), please also read the notes in code as well. For the 3rd or more child you'll need to add 1 or more implementation besides the vector definition.  Orphan rule has no limitation here unless `Childs` trait comes from another crate

Answer (score 1):

No you can't pattern match on types, but no you don't need another trait, the implementation of the trait bound is exactly where you would implement that, because only the methods and functions of and provided for a trait you bind on are available so you should implement the different behavior on it.

```rust
trait Childs {
    fn push_either(self, a: &mut Vec<Child1>, b: &mut Vec<Child2>);
}
struct Child1;
impl Childs for Child1 {
    fn push_either(self, a: &mut Vec<Child1>, _: &mut Vec<Child2>) {
        a.push(self);
    }
}
struct Child2;
impl Childs for Child2 {
    fn push_either(self, _: &mut Vec<Child1>, b: &mut Vec<Child2>) {
        b.push(self);
    }
}

struct Other {
    c1s: Vec<Child1>,
    c2s: Vec<Child2>,
}
impl Other {
    fn something<C: Childs>(&mut self, o: C) {
        o.push_either(&mut self.c1s, &mut self.c2s);
    }
}
```

Comment: "No you can't pattern match on types" that's not *entirely* true, you could take something like an `&dyn Any` and downcast. Your version is clearly better though. For an open set at least, since the original is a closed set, I'd say `Childs` should not be a trait, instead it should be an `enum Childs { Child1(Child1), Child2(Child2) }`. This also works with a dynamic payload: if the information is always static you might as well have two different methods, one for Child1 and one for Child2.

Comment: You're right one could [use `Any` and `downcast(_ref)`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cda514f0781be240ca0deec2999c7108) I'd hardly call that pattern matching on a type, but it is a different way to 'dispatch' I guess.

Comment: Thank you! This does answer the question clearly, but... not what I was hoping for. I updated the question. And, I wouldn't want to do the casting because the whole point here is I'm hoping for high performance static dispatch. The code in the question is a simplification of my actual code, but I did initially have two methods as Masklinn suggests. I'm hoping to better understand elegant solutions in rust for this type of thing.